# How to set AngularJs value to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing a event scheduler application using back end as slim framework and front end as AngularJs. Here how to assign a value from slim api to javascript variable.Below is my code.
I am using calendar to schedule the event.

```
<body ng-app="calenderApp" ng-controller="calenderCtrl">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <div class="box box-primary">
                        <div class="box-body no-padding">
                          <div id="calendar"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
            <script src="plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="angularjs/calender.js"></script>
     </body>
```

my javascript to pin the event on the calendar is:

```
     var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate(),
            m = date.getMonth(),
            y = date.getFullYear();
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          buttonText: {
            today: 'today',
            month: 'month',
            week: 'week',
            day: 'day'
          },
          //Random default events
          events: [
            {
              title: 'All Day Event',
              start: new Date(y, m, 1),
              backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
              borderColor: "#f56954" //red
            },
            {
              title: 'Long Event',
              start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
              end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
              backgroundColor: "#f39c12", //yellow
              borderColor: "#f39c12" //yellow
            },
            {
              title: 'Meeting',
              start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
              allDay: false,
              backgroundColor: "#0073b7", //Blue
              borderColor: "#0073b7" //Blue
            },
            {
              title: 'Lunch',
              start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
              end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
              allDay: false,
              backgroundColor: "#00c0ef", //Info (aqua)
              borderColor: "#00c0ef" //Info (aqua)
            },
            {
              title: 'Birthday Party',
              start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
              end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
              allDay: false,
              backgroundColor: "#00a65a", //Success (green)
              borderColor: "#00a65a" //Success (green)
            },
            {
              title: 'Click for Google',
              start: new Date(y, m, 28),
              end: new Date(y, m, 29),
              url: 'http://google.com/',
              backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc", //Primary (light-blue)
              borderColor: "#3c8dbc" //Primary (light-blue)
            }
          ],
          editable: false,
          droppable: false, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
          drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            copiedEventObject.backgroundColor = $(this).css("background-color");
            copiedEventObject.borderColor = $(this).css("border-color");

            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
              // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
              $(this).remove();
            }

          }
        });
</script>
```

my AngularJs file to get the event:

```
var app = angular.module('calenderApp', []);
app.controller('calenderCtrl', ['$scope', '$http' ,function($scope, $http)
{
getInfo();
function getInfo()
{
    $http.post("http://localhost/AdminLTE-master/sis_crm/route/campaign/campaign/view").then(function(response) {
        $scope.names = response.data.records;
    });
}
}]);
```

Here how can i set the value to variables like title, start, backgroundColor, borderColor that are received from the api.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all save Your data to variable:

```
 events = [ //global variable without var
        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: new Date(y, m, 1),
          backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
          borderColor: "#f56954" //red
        },
        {
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
          end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
          backgroundColor: "#f39c12", //yellow
          borderColor: "#f39c12" //yellow
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
          allDay: false,
          backgroundColor: "#0073b7", //Blue
          borderColor: "#0073b7" //Blue
        },
        {
          title: 'Lunch',
          start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
          end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
          allDay: false,
          backgroundColor: "#00c0ef", //Info (aqua)
          borderColor: "#00c0ef" //Info (aqua)
        },
        {
          title: 'Birthday Party',
          start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
          end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
          allDay: false,
          backgroundColor: "#00a65a", //Success (green)
          borderColor: "#00a65a" //Success (green)
        },
        {
          title: 'Click for Google',
          start: new Date(y, m, 28),
          end: new Date(y, m, 29),
          url: 'http://google.com/',
          backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc", //Primary (light-blue)
          borderColor: "#3c8dbc" //Primary (light-blue)
        }
      ];
```

next use it

```
     var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate(),
        m = date.getMonth(),
        y = date.getFullYear();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      buttonText: {
        today: 'today',
        month: 'month',
        week: 'week',
        day: 'day'
      },
      //Random default events
      events: events, //here used it
      editable: false,
      droppable: false, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
      drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

        // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
        var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

        // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
        var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

        // assign it the date that was reported
        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
        copiedEventObject.backgroundColor = $(this).css("background-color");
        copiedEventObject.borderColor = $(this).css("border-color");

        // render the event on the calendar
        // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
          // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
          $(this).remove();
        }

      }
    });
```

in angular:

```
function getInfo()
{
    $http.post("http://localhost/AdminLTE-  master/sis_crm/route/campaign/campaign/view").then(function(response) {
    $scope.names = response.data.records;
    events[0].title="new title"; //here You are changing standard js variable outside angular scope
    //refresh fullcalendar
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
});
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help..!!how can i use events and #calendar?

Comment: events are used in my example in calendar config, so changing them should change in calendar, but must be use $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents"); If it is not what you need then please describe.

Comment: how can use it..$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
...
events:events
....
});

Comment: Ok I edited with copied all code from You. It is ok now?